# Get storage item as a string and not an object

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

With the code below I am attempting to retrieve a weblink from an ionic storage key value pair.

```
loadpage(){

    let weblink = this.storage.get('link').then((val) => {
        JSON.stringify(val);
        console.log('Your link is', val);
    });

    this.http.get(weblink)
        .timeout(2000)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.mainContact = data;
            this.storage.set ("mainContact", JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            err => {
                this.connectionAlert();
            }
        );
}
```

My error is I am attempting to stringify 'weblink', but it is still an object.  how would I convert 'weblink' to string for use with the http.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weblink` here is a `Promise` object waiting to be fullfilled. Given the asynchronous nature, http request is performing it on the `Promise` object created by the `storage` engine, before it gets evaluated. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

If you are intending to use `weblink` for the http request, one way to overcome this is shifting the call inside the `.then` where you will have the value resolved by the `Promise`. Let us know if still in doubt.

```
loadpage() { //this part is in your loadpage
    this.storage.get('link').then((val) => {

        this.performWebRequest(val); //this 
        //or  performWebRequest(JSON.stringify(val)) depending on the value stored
        console.log('Your link is', val);
    });
}

performWebRequest(weblink) {
    this.http.get(weblink)
    .timeout(2000)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.mainContact = data;
        this.storage.set("mainContact", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
        err => {
        this.connectionAlert();
    });

}
```

Comment: Getting a Typescript Error at  performWebRequest(weblink)   says ';' expected.  I am going try and run this down.  But I do understand your point.   When I get this working I will accept the answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ThomasDegroot, I've  just updated the code snippet, considering typescript.. Nothing big just that the storage get request is in the  loadpage function and `this.preformWebRequest` ..

Comment: Yes I came up with something similar, but your answer is cleaner than mine.  Thanks a lot for the help.